# I want to add horizontal tabs in the Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, admin, tabs

I want to show horizontal tabs in the Magento 2 admin and inside each tab, there will be a form created using ui_component.

[image]

Just like this, can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: where you want to add these tabs?

Comment: in a custom page.

Answer (score 0):

Magento documentation for tabs —

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_tabs.html

Alternatively Webkul has a tutorial —

https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-use-magento-tabs-widget/